# Письмо с новостной рассылкой обрезается в gmail

Tags: дефект

Подписан на еженедельную новостную рассылку со своей gmail-почтой, просматриваю её в браузере.

Каждый раз, когда получаю письмо, в конце вижу

```
...

[Message clipped]  View entire message
```

Я точно получал бОльшие письма, и они при этом выводились полностью.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы их содержимое не обрезалось?

[image: Обрезанное письмо из рассылки]

Возможно, в письме содержится слишком много кода для оформления постов и оно обрезается из-за превышения максимальной длины по символам, но я не уверен в этом.

Comment: А это разве не ваш почтовый сервак обрезает при просмотре?

Comment: Да, похоже, что обрезает сервер, но не вижу причины, по которой нельзя было бы уменьшить размер письма, раз есть такое ограничение у некоторой части пользователей.

Answer (score 2):

Проблеме уже два года как минимум, она обсуждалась на главной мете:

- [Please condense the markup for Stack Exchange newsletters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308536/please-condense-the-markup-for-stack-exchange-newsletters)
- [Last entry in newsletter has messed-up user links, gravatars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306533/last-entry-in-newsletter-has-messed-up-user-links-gravatars)

Пока ответа от компании нет :(

> Возможно, в письме содержится слишком много кода для оформления постов и оно обрезается из-за превышения максимальной длины по символам, ...

Совершенно верно, Gmail обрезает письма больше 102КБ и, технически, проблема на их стороне. С другой стороны, Stack Overflow в своих рассылках использует неоправданно большое количество трекинговых ссылок и вполне может оптимизировать длину кода.